Is there a way to target woocommerce-order-data__heading
Is there a way to target the woocommerce-order-data__heading containing the order number and the name of the customer? I need to pass this data to WP ALL Export so I wonder if there is an option to get this data.

You can follow this guide by WP ALL Import on how to Create Custom Order Export Columns Using PHP, and use some of these variables in your export
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);, $order_number = $order->get_order_number();, and $customer_name = $order->get_billing_first_name() . ' ' . $order->get_billing_last_name();.
